# Position Enlarged Image On Hover

Tags: html, image, hover

Please see: http://silverbacksport.com/rugby_collection.html

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<table style="width: 100%" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="9" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style5" style="width: 167px">
            <img alt="" src="Images/RUGBY%20-%20Template1%20-%20thumb.jpg" 
                onmouseover="this.src='Images/RUGBY - Template1.gif'"
                onmouseout="this.src='Images/RUGBY - Template1 - thumb.jpg'" />
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style5" style="width: 167px">
            <img alt="" src="Images/RUGBY%20-%20Template2%20-%20thumb.jpg"
                onmouseover="this.src='Images/RUGBY - Template2.gif'"
                onmouseout="this.src='Images/RUGBY - Template2 - thumb.jpg'" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can position the enlarged image onmouseover so that it stays within the limits of the vertical borders of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-width` for this.

```
img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

This way, you will control the extent to which the image will expand. You can use this `max-width` to the container of the image, and use `width: 100%` to the image. This way, browser will automatically check the resolution which will be best for the current container size.

Comment: Thank you Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan but, sorry if I am appearing a bit dim:

Comment: Thank you @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan but, sorry if I am appearing a bit dim: when you say add max-width to the container of the image, is the container the <td>?. And, where can I add width:100% to the image given: onmouseover="this.src='Images/LM CAP (2013).jpg'" ?

Comment: Sure thing I mean to say `td`. And no this is a CSS property, so you will add it inside .css file.

Comment: One more query please @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan? The pages with thumbnail images expanding on hover now work great. But now, the max-width CSS property also is applied to the images in the slider on the Home Page, which I want to be full original size. Is there a way to fix? CSS:.rotating-item {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

Comment: The CSS for the slider images:                                       .rotating-item {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

Comment: Then you can try to seperate them out, using a class so that they are different. And then you can use a seperate class or id to do the onmouseover change, this way only the images with exact class will get the change and others will be neglected! Can I get a fiddle? @user2909454..

Comment: No fiddle yet :-). I just cannot figure it out. See: http://silverbacksport.com/ and  http://silverbacksport.com/rugby_collection.html. CSS: 
#content {
 float: left;
 width: 646px;
 padding: 15px;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative;
}
#content img {
 display: block;
 max-width:400px;
}
#rotating-item-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 540px;
 height: 512px;
}
.rotating-item {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}                          Sorry, you are dealing with a newbie here!

Comment: Fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/NevNic/6Hn6X/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/NevNic/5rNPe/